# Java Says Integers are Null When They Just Worked

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make an rpg game, and right now, I'm trying to load maps from a text file. I copied and pasted the first layer code for both the second and third layers, but it only works for the first one. I get a null exception error when it tries to make a new BasicTile in the second layer. According to the error, the arrayId and imageId are null, but I can't understand why. Please help, and thank you!!!

```
//MapLoader Function
public void load(String path){
    mapLayer1 = new Tile[tilesWidth + 1][tilesHeight + 1];
    mapLayer2 = new Tile[tilesWidth + 1][tilesHeight + 1];
    mapLayer3 = new Tile[tilesWidth + 1][tilesHeight + 1];

    try{

        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        int y = 0;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //Tile Layer 1
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("[LAYERTWO]")) break;
            String[] val = line.split(" ");

            for(int x = 0; x < tilesWidth; x++){
                String[] value = val[x].split(",");
                int arrayId = Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
                int imageId = Integer.parseInt(value[1]);
                if(arrayId == 0 && imageId == 4){ //Water
                    Tile tile = new AnimatedTile(x, y, arrayId, imageId, new int[] {0,1,2,1}, 750);
                    tilesLayer1.add(tile);
                    mapLayer1[x][y] = tile;
                }else{
                    Tile tile = new BasicTile(x, y, arrayId, imageId);
                    tilesLayer1.add(tile);
                    mapLayer1[x][y] = tile;
                }
            }
            y++;
        }

        y = 0;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //Tile Layer 2
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("[LAYERTHREE]")) break;
            String[] val = line.split(" ");

            for(int x = 0; x < tilesWidth; x++){
                String[] value = val[x].split(",");
                int arrayId = Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
                int imageId = Integer.parseInt(value[1]);
                if(arrayId == 0 && imageId == 4){ //Water
                    Tile tile = new AnimatedTile(x, y, arrayId, imageId, new int[] {0,1,2,1}, 750);
                    tilesLayer2.add(tile);
                    mapLayer2[x][y] = tile;
                }else{
                    Tile tile = new BasicTile(x, y, arrayId, imageId);
                    tilesLayer2.add(tile);
                    mapLayer2[x][y] = tile;
                }
            }
            y++;
        }

        y = 0;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //Tile Layer 3
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("[COLLIDERS]")) break;
            String[] val = line.split(" ");

            for(int x = 0; x < tilesWidth; x++){
                String[] value = val[x].split(",");
                int arrayId = Integer.parseInt(value[0]);
                int imageId = Integer.parseInt(value[1]);
                if(arrayId == 0 && imageId == 4){ //Water
                    Tile tile = new AnimatedTile(x, y, arrayId, imageId, new int[] {0,1,2,1}, 750);
                    tilesLayer3.add(tile);
                    mapLayer3[x][y] = tile;
                }else{
                    Tile tile = new BasicTile(x, y, arrayId, imageId);
                    tilesLayer3.add(tile);
                    mapLayer3[x][y] = tile;
                }
            }
            y++;
        }

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ //Colliders
            String[] val = line.split(" ");

            colliders.add(new Rectangle(Integer.parseInt(val[0]), Integer.parseInt(val[1]), Integer.parseInt(val[2]), Integer.parseInt(val[3])));
        }

        in.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then this is the BaseTile Class.

```
//BasicTile Class
public class BasicTile extends Tile{

    public BasicTile(int tileX, int tileY, int arrayId, int imageId) {
        super(tileX, tileY, arrayId, imageId);
    }

    public void update() {}

    public void render() {
        Handler.g.drawImage(image, tileX * Tile.WIDTH, tileY * Tile.HEIGHT, tileWidth * Tile.WIDTH, tileHeight * Tile.HEIGHT, null);
    }

}
```

And this is what BasicTile inherits from, the Tile Class.

```
public abstract class Tile {

    public static final int WIDTH = 32;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 32;

    protected int tileX;
    protected int tileY;
    protected int tileWidth;
    protected int tileHeight;
    protected int arrayId;
    protected int imageId;
    protected BufferedImage image;

    public Tile(int tileX, int tileY, int arrayId, int imageId){
        this.tileX = tileX;
        this.tileY = tileY;
        this.arrayId = arrayId;
        this.imageId = imageId;

        switch(arrayId){
        case 0: 
            this.image = ImageHandler.getTileImage(imageId); 
            this.tileWidth = this.image.getWidth() / Tile.WIDTH; //This is where the error came up in the console.
            this.tileHeight = this.image.getHeight() / Tile.HEIGHT; 
            break;
        }
    }

    public abstract void update();

    public abstract void render();

}
```

Again, thank you for all your help. I know this is a lot of stuff to look at, but I didn't know what all you guys would need. I commented where I was getting the error in the Tile Class, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When `Integer.parseInt` is called and `null` is returned, this means that the string has 0 length. I would check the elements of the array before you pass them into the `parseInt` method.

FYI, here is the relevant section from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

> The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.

Comment: Thank you @SimplicityGuy . Right now it's splitting the string "0,3" from the comma, so I just figured it would grab the first and second elements all nice and dandily like it did in the first layer. xD

Comment: @Ctsmario: did you try setting a breakpoint on those lines and validating that indeed these values are what you expect them to be? You're right that with the string "0,3" you should see values[0] = 0 and values[1] = 3, but it's good to verify that the data is what you really expect it to be.

Comment: I haven't, but I will now. Do you just mean adding maybe System.out.printlns throughout the code by "setting a breakpoint"? I'm pretty new to Java, so I don't understand much of the technical talk. Sorry about that.

Comment: Printlns will work. But if you're using Eclipse or other IDE, you can set breakpoints that pause code execution while you look at the variables. Highly recommended to make full usage of your development environment.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need. Could you please explain to me how to do that, though? I'm really sorry to bug you.

Comment: I would recommend installing Eclipse. For instance, here is the documentation for how breakpoints work in Java in Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_line_breakpoints.htm

Comment: Thank you, again. @SimplicityGuy I found exactly where the error occurs. It successfully goes through the first layer, no problem. Then it goes to the second layer, and works for the first three tiles. Then it crashes. And I don't feel that it makes sense.

Comment: Ok! Glad to be of help. Sounds like you have some debugging to do on the input of your data.

Comment: No kidding! And thank you for telling me about breakpoints; I probably would never have found out about them. :D @SimplicityGuy

Comment: You have saved me, @SimplicityGuy . I can't thank you enough. I would post a picture, but I'm not exactly sure how to at the moment, so I'll just go. Gracias!